# Debug Xamarin Forms - Asp Core Web Api - via USB phone connection - on Time out

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to access to my Api Rest with a **Xamarin Forms** app. Xamarin is on debug on my phone (Android) connected by USB

Api Rest  : Asp.Net Core launch in debug on local , access ok with postman on localhost : GET & POST ok

I have **connection time out** when I try to access to my GET or POST using Refit or simple HttpClient with ip like 10.0.2.2:51213

Any ideas plz ?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Whether the phone and PC are in the same network ? Need to keep them in the same network segment . You can have a try with browser of phone to check whether can get data first . If browser works , then continue to check in xamarin .

Comment: Thanks. My first mistake was believing that the phone usb connection is like emulator without passing by wifi network... thanks for the tip !
A friend guided me to test ngrok to expose my localhost to simplify the process.

Comment: Great be helpful ! Would you mind updaing this as an answer , and this will help other people to know how to solve this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was believing that the phone usb connection is like emulator without passing by wifi network

A easy practice is to use NGrok to expose my localhost Api adress to simplify the process [NGrok site web](https://ngrok.com/) and consume this url in my Xamarin app

Just verify the url each time you launch ngrok if you use the free version